# Looping TCP Communication C++

Tags: c++, tcp

I have a C++ application which receives 1 char and runs a function dependent on which char it has received. The problem is that the application stops as soon as it has received one message.

**I need the application to start listening on the same port again after it has received a message** but I haven't managed to do so. I tried looping it with a "while (true)" loop but I get errors.

It may also be worth noting that after the server has ran successfully it gives the message:

> ** * stack smashing detected ***:  terminated
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

And if I try to run the server again on the same port after it has successfully completed I get:

> ERROR on binding: Address already in use

Significant code:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
socklen_t clilen;
char buffer[1];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int n;
if (argc < 2) {
 fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
 exit(1);
}
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0)
error("ERROR opening socket");
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portno = atoi(argv[1]);
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
      sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
      error("ERROR on binding");
listen(sockfd,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
         (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,
         &clilen);
if (newsockfd < 0)
  error("ERROR on accept");
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
if (buffer[0] == '0') {
    lamp();
}
else {
    printf("No valid input from client.\n");
}
if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
close(newsockfd);
close(sockfd);
return 0;
```

}

EDIT: I should've mentioned that I am very new to C++. Please give an example with your solution.

Comment: The problems you have are two distinct and different problems. The first is because you have a *buffer overflow* in your code, the second is because the socket is in `TIME-WAIT` state (see [this TCP protocol operation reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation) for a list of states) and you haven't set the `SO_REUSEADDR` option on the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char buffer[1]; ... bzero(buffer,256);`

Of course, after you've corrupted the whole stack it's understandable that other reasonable code is suddenly failing.

Comment: I'm new to C++. Could you tell me how I can fix it?

Comment: @Jancoz: The code is old C, not modern C++. The smallest fix would be `char buffer = 0;`. Drop the `bzero`, it's overkill. Also, `read` one character instead of 255.